# mongodb sharding, use multiple fields as the shard key?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have documents with the following schema:

```
{
  idents: {
    list: ['foo', 'bar', ...],
    id: 123
  }
  ...
}
```

the field idents.list is an array of string and always contains at least one element.
the field idents.id may or may not be existant.

over time more entries are added to 'idents.list' and at some point in the future the field idents.id may be set too.

these two fields are used to clearly identify a document and therefore are relevant for a shard key. 
is it possible to use sharding with this schema?

UPDATE:
documents are always queried via `{idents.list: 'foo'}` OR `{ $or: [ {idents.list: 'foo'}, {idents.id: 42} ] }`

Comment: We can use multiple fields for a shard key. But by using multiple keys, we can never have hashed shard key on it. That's my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,you can do this. The documentation says:

```
Use a compound shard key that uses two or three values from all documents that provide the right mix of cardinality with scalable write operations and query isolation.
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/

Comment: The doc says that a shard key can never change, in my use case the list changes over time. so it does not seem that this makes sense as a shard key. does sharding help at all when querying is seldom/never done via the shardkey's entries? updating/writing on the other hand can be done through the shard key (e.g. a hashed _id)

Comment: if you don't use the shard key to query, the you will have a scatter-gather query which won't be efficient. You can't use `$update` for a shard key content, that is correct, but you can remove the document and insert a new one. It might not be efficient if you do it often, but considering how mongodb re-allocates space when you increase array sizes, it might not make much difference.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I didnt think of that possibility. removing and reinserting of course is problbematic in some ways because of concurrent writes... sharding is not trivial it seems to me, fortunately at the moment it is not neccessary